# List of all reported bacteria

Tags: microbiology, bacteriology

I would like to know were to download a table file with all reported bacteria and its corresponding PHYLUM, CLASS, ORDER and FAMILY.

Basically, its the same table than [this one](http://genomesonline.org/documents/Export/gold.xls) from [GOLD genomes](http://genomesonline.org/cgi-bin/GOLD/index.cgi) but containing the non-sequenced bacteria too:

Thanks for you help, Bernardo

Answer (score 6):

I am not sure if such a complete list exists. There are some lists available, which look pretty complete. Have a look at [Labrat](http://www.thelabrat.com/protocols/Bacterialspecies/) and [Microbexpert](http://www.microbexpert.com/AtoZ/Bacteria_AtoZ/Bacteria_AtoZ.html). There is also a book available, which contains an approved list of bacterial names, see [here](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/books/NBK814/). Otherwise you can of course search your way through [PubMed](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed) and see, what comes out.

Comment: Thanks Chris, but I need the list in table format (tab or comma delimited file). I couldn't find this option in the websites you suggested.

Comment: Oh, I am not sure if this list exists at all. You could try to contact these websites and ask them if they can provide this data in a different format.